# C# interop with array pointer as short without unsafe

Tags: c#, pointers, interop

I am quite inexperienced with Interop in C# and struggling with a Pointer issue right now. I have an external compiled DLL and a C# API (cannot change things in there). The Interop code itself looks like (and must bot be changed)

```
[DllImport("FWLIB32.dll", EntryPoint="cnc_rdcurrent")]
public static extern short cnc_rdcurrent( ushort FlibHndl, out short a );
```

The second argument is (by documentation) the address of a short array, where the external call will put the data into. The actual size is determined at runtime.

Currently, I am thinking about something like (untested)

```
            short* c = stackalloc short[N];
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) c[i] = 0;
            short cc = (short)c;

            int NCReadCode = Focas1.cnc_rdcurrent(flibHndl, out cc);
```

But this needs unsafe code. As the rest of the application is completely safe (other API members use predefined structs instead of explicit memory addresses)

So, is there a way of doing this without unsafe code? (Secondly, if you find flaws in my idea I am also happy to hear ;) )

Thank you all!

Comment: It would be helpful, if you provide the C definition of the unmanaged `cnc_rdcurrent` function. Check also the following: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/marshaling-different-types-of-arrays.

Comment: The definition on the C side is given as:
 
  short WINAPI cnc_rdcurrent(unsigned short FlibHndl,short *crrnt);

Comment: Is there anyway you could get it working, I am only getting run time exceptions while using this function? I am really curious to know and needful

Answer (score 0):

So, if the number of elements `N` is known and defined elsewhere as specified above, I would recommend the following:

```
[DllImport("FWLIB32.dll", EntryPoint="cnc_rdcurrent")]
public static extern short cnc_rdcurrent( ushort FlibHndl, ref short[] crrnt );
```

When used:

```
// Create result array, reserve memory on managed heap
// Items are initialized to 0 by default
short[] resultArray = new short[N];

int NCReadCode = Focas1.cnc_rdcurrent(flibHndl, ref resultArray);
```

So, your managed assembly is responsible for the array memory management, and the unmanaged DLL copies the result into the preallocated memory. There is no need for unsafe code.

Comment: I am not able/allowed to change the Interop code segment itself

Comment: Hmm, that's bad. In your provided example you are casting the unmanged array address to a short (16 bit) value, that will not work.